# Pass JSON String into Jstree

Tags: json, jsp, jstree

I'm, Having trouble passing JSON data into the Jstree.

Following is my Jstree

```
       $("#tree")
       .bind("open_node.jstree", function (event, data) {   
            console.log(data.rslt.obj.attr("id"));     

        }) 
       .jstree({
        "plugins" : ["themes", "json_data", "ui"],
    "json_data" : {
        "data":    [{"data":'Top Level - ',"state":'closed',"attr":{"seq_no":341386}}], 
        "state" : "open",
         "ajax": {   
            "type": 'POST', 
            "dataType": 'json',
            "data": {"action": 'getChildren'},  
            "url": function (node) { 
            var nodeId = node.attr('seq_no');         
                 return 'ajax/test.jsp?seq_no=' + 341386;       
            }, 
            "success": function (new_data) {

                return new_data;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

### And test.jsp looks like this:

```
RecordCollection result=null;
PlsqlSelectCommand selCmd =  null;

String sErrorMsg = "";
String sqlSelect;

OutputFormat    format  = new OutputFormat( doc );   //Serialize DOM
StringWriter    xmlOut = new StringWriter();        //Writer will be a String
XMLSerializer   serial = new XMLSerializer( xmlOut, format ); 
serial.serialize(doc);



JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlOut.toString());
<%=jsonObject%>
```

---

The problem is JSON data isnt passed into the jstree. thus I cant set my children nodes. I've tried so hard but can't get this working.

Is there something else I need to do in order to pass this JSON string into the jstree. 
My jstree works when the data feed is hard-coded.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide sample of your ajax json? Or the best would be to create jsfiddle ajax.